# how to work on same search tab on multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, dhtml

I have around ten html pages all have search tab ,only one page is dedicated to display the search result , from which ever page i enter search it directs to search page and displays output ,is their any better method to do this? 
I am using jquery on clientside and webservices written in c# on the server side and i am not using master pages .

Comment: i think ajax call can help you in this case. ref:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display the result in the current html page then add a div like thath:

```
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

and do an ajax request for the search.html and display the returned string like that:

```
$("#search-result").html(resulting_string);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,my search page displays google map with markers and sidebar in it can i return this to the called page?

Comment: what do you mean by return this to the called page? you mean pass it to the page that does the search?